# Positioning many groups in SVG

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to position a scale with numbers and lines on the top of my black half-circle gauge. The problem is that I have two groups of elements that do not fit with each other in the same group .. Thus the local coordinate system of the scale element is located on the bottom and I cannot use transform functions to place it in the center..

```js
var r = 400;
var circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
var total_circles = circles.length;
for (var i = 0; i < total_circles; i++) {
  circles[i].setAttribute('r', r);
}

var meter_dimension = (r * 2) + 100;
var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
wrapper.style.width = meter_dimension + 'px';
wrapper.style.height = meter_dimension + 'px';

var cf = 2 * Math.PI * r;
var semi_cf = cf / 2;
var z = 40 * Math.PI;
document.querySelector('#outline_ends')
  .setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', 2 + ',' + (semi_cf - 2)); -
document.querySelector('#mask')
  .setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', semi_cf + ',' + cf);
document.querySelector('#low')
  .setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', semi_cf - z + ',' + cf);

for (i = 0; i <= 180; i = i + 10) {
  var new_tick = noon.cloneNode(true);
  new_tick.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].textContent = i;
  new_tick.removeAttribute("id");
  new_tick.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + i + " 0 0)");
  gauge.appendChild(new_tick);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

#meter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
}

#mask {
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 60;
}

.black {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 30;
}

.range {
  stroke-width: 60;
}

.scale {
  stroke: #ffffff;
}

rect {
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <svg id="meter">
    <g class="scale">                
      <circle id="mask" class="circle" cx="50%" cy="50%">
      </circle>
      <circle id="low" class="black" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="360">
      </circle>
      <circle id="outline_ends" class="circle outline" cx="50%" cy="50%">
      </circle>
        <g id="gauge" transform="rotate(-90)">
          <g id="noon">
            <rect x="-10" y="-220" width="20" height="100" />
            <line x1="0" y1="-190" x2="0" y2="-180" />
            <text x="0" y="-200"></text>
          </g>
        </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show a desired result pls to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of positioning a group in SVG:
You put the group in the `<defs>` and you reuse it with `<use>`. The `<use>` element may have a x and a y attributes that are defining the new position.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; max-height:100vh;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 75">
 <defs>
  <g id="g1">
    <rect width="20" height="20" />"
  </g>
  </defs> 
  <use xlink:href ="#g1" x="100" y="50"/>
  <use xlink:href ="#g1" x="50" y="10" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

In the example above I draw the same group twice, every time in a different position.

Comment: I am trying to avoid hard-coded setting of coordinates and prefer to use width, height percentage values to make it dynamic.. For example I avoid using viewBox..  However in this case I guess I have to make an exception..

Comment: No you don't have to. In the code above you may replace `viewBox="0 0 200 75"` with `width="200" height="75"`